# sending mail in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail

I am using rails 2.3.8. I am trying to send mail through action mailer. When i call the mailer function it does not throw any error and completes successfully even the log shows that the mail is sent. But when i check the mail box there is not mail sent actually Is there any problem with sendmail configuration or something else. Please help me out with it.

Thanks

Here are my setting in `development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
  :location => "path/to/sendmail",
  :arguments => "-i"
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the configurations you set up for the ActionMailer to work.

Comment: Read up on the basics: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: I have read that guide but still I am not able to send email with these configurations. I only want it to be sent from local server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if

> config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

dont work
maybe a sendmail misconfiguration , try to send a mail from bash and check the output

```
touch file.log;
cat - file.log << EOF | sendmail -t
to:email@address.com
from:you@address.com
subject:Testing 123
TEST
EOF
```

otherwise
I find  useful to use this program (a fake smtp server) to test outgoing mail 
http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `development.rb` file

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

because i don't see it in your configuration